# join multiple tables with "GROUP BY" and latest date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

i have 2 mysql tables

table 1 is "qualitaet-inventar" and has 3000 rows with "sachnummer" as AUTO_INCREMENT

[image]

table 2 is "qualitaet" and has a couple of rows.. here is "id" set to AUTO_INCREMENT
the important thing is that "sachnummer" can be exist many times. (see the red marks in picture)

[image]

what i want to do is a left join from "qualitaet" to "qualitaet-inventar"

i want to group all "sachnummer" by showing the latest date of "created" on "qualitaet"

and when a "sachnummer" isn't available in "qualitaet" do an empty join to "qualitaet-inventar"

so i have this code

```
SELECT 
    i.`sachnummer` AS id,
    MAX(q.`created`) AS letztemessung,
    i.`sachnummer-name` AS sachnummer
FROM
        `qualitaet-inventar` i
LEFT JOIN
        `qualitaet` q on i.`sachnummer` = q.`sachnummer`
GROUP BY
        sachnummer
ORDER BY
    sachnummer ASC
```

the problem is that it needs a long time to get this result

[image]

with this code it works faster

```
SELECT 
    q.`sachnummer` AS id,
    MAX(q.`created`) AS letztemessung,
    i.`sachnummer-name` AS sachnummer
FROM
    qualitaet q
LEFT JOIN
    `qualitaet-inventar` i on q.`sachnummer` = i.`sachnummer`
GROUP BY
    sachnummer
ORDER BY
    sachnummer ASC
```

but i don't get the hole inventory and an empty date with this code

[image]

is it possible to get this table in a faster way for high table-rows? :D

[image]

edit:

here are my indexes

[image]

Comment: Your two queries are fundamentally the same. by changing the `from` and `join` clauses around like that, all you've done is essentially switched between a `LEFT` and a `RIGHT` join. Make sure you've got indexes on ALL of the fields you're using in the where/join/group clauses.

Comment: If you add the condition `WHERE q.\`sachnummer\` IS NULL` to your first query, how long does it take to run? Also, if you run the first query immediately after the second query, does it still take as long? (The performance discrepancy between the first and second query *may* have been due to the RDBMS re-using cached data when running the second query.)

Comment: @MarkBannister the first query with where -> Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 1,087 total, Query took 22.8324 sec) and the second turn needs  22.7028 sec

Comment: Have you checked whether any of the tables or indexes involved needs to be repaired? 34 seconds is a long time for 3000 rows.

Comment: i made a screenshot of the indexes (see my edited question). is there a function or a hint to repair?

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rebuilding-tables.html

Comment: i found Analyse table and Repair table in table -> Operations -> Table maintenance.. and get a ok to both tables

Comment: See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-files.html - this might *conceivably* be related to temp space issues. It might also be worth asking this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: i checked my xampp folder.. there are 2 tmp folders. c://xampp/php/tmp is empty and c://xampp/tmp has only session files and a lot of empty ib60A7... .tmp files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *shouldn't* work any faster than your existing query - but from your description, *may* do:

```
SELECT i.`sachnummer` AS id,
       MAX(q.`created`) AS letztemessung,
       i.`sachnummer-name` AS sachnummer
FROM `qualitaet-inventar` i
JOIN `qualitaet` q on i.`sachnummer` = q.`sachnummer`
GROUP BY sachnummer
UNION ALL
SELECT i.`sachnummer` AS id,
       q.`created` AS letztemessung,
       i.`sachnummer-name` AS sachnummer
FROM `qualitaet-inventar` i
LEFT JOIN `qualitaet` q on i.`sachnummer` = q.`sachnummer`
WHERE q.`sachnummer` IS NULL
ORDER BY sachnummer ASC
```

Another possibility:

```
select id, max(letztemessung) as letztemessung, max(sachnummer) as sachnummer
from
(SELECT `sachnummer` AS id,
        `created` AS letztemessung,
        '' AS sachnummer
 FROM `qualitaet` q
 UNION ALL
 SELECT `sachnummer` AS id,
        cast(null as datetime) AS letztemessung,
        `sachnummer-name` AS sachnummer
 FROM `qualitaet-inventar` i
) sq
group by id 
ORDER BY sachnummer ASC
```

Comment: your code: Showing rows 0 - 2999 ( 3,000 total, Query took 22.5699 sec) 10 seconds faster :) but not enough :D

Comment: @bernte: I've added another possible variant - can you check how long this one takes?

Comment: second code: Showing rows 0 - 2999 ( 3,000 total, Query took 0.0176 sec) why?????? :D

Comment: The query isn't doing any explicit joining, although the RDBMS should normally do a better job of joining than this. :/

Comment: maybe its a problem that i use xampp?

Comment: marked this answer as accepted! but don't understand it :D i will check the tmp part. thank you mark

Comment: @bemte: I don't understand it, either - I'm glad that this is a reasonable workaround, but (as mentioned above) you might get a better answer on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ . Also, you're welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the general idea, with shorter table names.

```
select somefields
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.something = t2.something
join (
select something, max(datetimefield) maxdt
from table1
where whatever
group by something
)  t3 on t1.something = t3.something
and t1.datetimefield = maxdt
where whatever
```