# How to get count of two fields from two different table with grouping a field from another table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have three tables `projects`, `discussions`, and `comments`.

I have tried it like this:

```
SELECT p.PRO_Name, COUNT( d.DIS_Id ) AS nofdisc, COUNT( c.COM_Id ) AS nofcom 
FROM projects p
LEFT JOIN discussions d ON p.PRO_Id = d.PRO_Id
LEFT JOIN comments c ON d.DIS_Id = c.DIS_Id
GROUP BY p.PRO_Name LIMIT 0 , 30
```

But it's taking all the rows from `discussions` and the count of `comments` is the same as the count of `discussions`.

Comment: What is the result you are expecting ? I think that you want to put `SELECT` in a `SELECT`

Comment: i want the total discussion corresponding to the project and total comments corresponding to the discussions.  I have checked this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134794/join-multiple-tables-with-group-by-and-latest-date-in-mysql" but logic is not clear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` counts the number of non-`null` values of the given parameter. The join you have will create a row per comment, where both `dis_id` and `com_id` are not `null`, so their counts would be the same. Since these are IDs, you could just count the **`distinct`** number of occurrences to get the response you'd want:

(EDIT: Added an `order by` clause as per the request in the comments)

```
SELECT    p.PRO_Name, 
          COUNT(DISTINCT d.DIS_Id) AS nofdisc,
          COUNT(DISTINCT c.COM_Id) AS nofcom 
FROM      projects p 
LEFT JOIN discussions d ON p.PRO_Id = d.PRO_Id 
LEFT JOIN comments c ON d.DIS_Id = c.DIS_Id 
GROUP BY  p.PRO_Name
ORDER BY  2,3 
LIMIT     0 , 30
```

Comment: Never seen distinct inside count function, but works like a charm..thanks mureinik. Could you tell if i can order by the counts of DIS_Id or COM_Id

Comment: what is 1, 2 in order clause, does 1 mean DIS_Id and 2 means COM_Id like that..??

Comment: @user3921707 arg, that was a mistake, should have been `order by 2, 3` (fixed already). As you guessed, these are ordinals referring to the select list. 2 is the 2nd column, `nofdisc`, and 3 is the 3rd, `nofcom`.

Comment: Another doubt, if i tried to get the greatest of date from the discussion, comments like GREATEST(d.DIS_Date, c.COM_Date) will it fetch the solution